# How to maintain JAVA projects irrespective of IDE (Netbeans and Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

In my team, some of them are using Netbeans and some of them using Eclipse, so in our Subversion repository for each JAVA project we have Netbeans & Eclipse project files.

I do want to keep Netbeans & Eclipse project setting files inside the JAVA project, they are specific to IDEs.

Please help me to maintain only the JAVA source files inside the subversion.

Comment: Well, delete them, and commit. What's the problem?

Comment: Problem is I have so many projects, which are inter dependent with each other, so every time, when I take the update from subversion, I have to configure the inter links.

Comment: You should not commit all the project in your svn. Only commit source folders, then in each different IDE you just have to checkout the source in a project created in the desired environment.

Comment: So, you would like the projects to be configured automagically, but without having the project files under subversion? It's one or the other. What's the problem in having the project files in subversion?

Answer (score 5):

Use a common build infrastructure, like **maven**. This encapsulates (as good as) all settings inside the maven pom.xml files (source encoding, java version etc.).

Also versioned library dependencies, subprojects are managed in maven.

NetBeans knows maven out-of-the-box, and eclipse has a good maven plugin.

*In my experience manual configuration, especially in eclipse, and grown ant scripts, are cumbersome.*